# How can I get rid of bloatware?

Tags: malware

MacOs supposedly has less bloatware than the other commercial OS' available. I have found that my mac has some.

Remote Management seems ingrained in the system very stubbornly; it may be the tip of the iceberg.

Could someone please publish a quick code segment to eliminate all the junk from macos?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132889/discussion-on-question-by-zerogwannabee-how-can-i-get-rid-of-bloatware).

Answer (score 2):

There exists no such "quick code segment" to remove "junk" from macOS.

The main reason is that the definition of "junk" varies from person to person. Some people might think that a feature is absolutely essential for the system, other's might never use it and consider it junk.

Comment: By junk I mean system apps like remote management.

Comment: That's not junk, and you wouldn't save a significant amount of space removing what is essentially a VNC server.  Just turn it off in System Preferences.